# How can I return a 404 error page in a node view?

Tags: nodes, users

How can I return a `404 error` page when a non-registered user tries to see a node page of a specific content type? And of course, the registered users can see the node page normally.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Setting permission is well covered in documentation. You have it done and now you only want to swap 403 -> 404?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal permission system provides fine grained permission control for "create", "edit", "delete" actions for every node content type, but viewing action is covered by general "View published content" permission option that covers all content types.

In order to deny access to anonymous users when they are trying to view a node of certain content type, you need to include a function in a custom module that implements `hook_node_access()`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_access().
 *
 * Disallow anonymous user to view nodes of type "EXAMPLE".
 */
function MYMODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  if (user_is_anonymous() && $op == 'view' && $node->type == 'EXAMPLE') {
    return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
  }
}
```

You need to replace MYMODULE with the module name that contains this function and EXAMPLE with the name of the content type that you wish to deny access to.

**UPDATE**: The code above would in fact return 403 (Access Denied) page, I'm sorry for confusion. The following code will return 404 (Page Not Found) page (only when user is trying to access the node of content type "example" in "full" view mode (usually by accessing the node by URL "node/NID]":

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 *
 * Disallow anonymous user to view nodes of type "EXAMPLE".
 */
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if (user_is_anonymous() && $view_mode == 'full' && $node->type == 'EXAMPLE') {
    drupal_not_found();
    drupal_exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: This will return 403, not 404.

Comment: It seems that returns two renders. One with the 404 error output and the other with the node view output.

Comment: ilaz, you are right. It seems that `drupal_not_found()` should be used with `drupal_exit()`, otherwise page is rendered twice. I updated the answer.

Comment: I'm glad to change my vote :)

Answer (score 1):

## Rabbit Hole

You can try using the [rabbit_hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module. It is available for:

- Drupal 7
- Drupal 8

Rabbit Hole is a module that adds the ability to control what should happen when an entity is being viewed at its own page.

Comment: For D8 See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152227/how-to-throw-404-error-in-drupal-module